# Show gallery by event PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to make a gallery of photos by event and date.

So for example :

```
**Trip 1**

[img1]  [img2]  [img3]

**Trip 2**

[img4] [img5]
```

I have 2 tables at database :

```
category_gallery  |   gallery
-----------------------------------
id_category       |  id
name              |  id_category (foreign_key)
date              |  link
```

How could i achieve this ? I have succeed to join the table and make a result like this :

```
id  |id_category | name  | date       | link
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 001        | trip1 | 01-01-2018 | www.xzx.cx/assets/images/001.jpg
2   | 001        | trip1 | 01-01-2018 | www.xzx.cx/assets/images/002.jpg
3   | 002        | trip2 | 02-02-2018 | www.xzx.cx/assets/images/003.jpg
```

But now i have no idea loop and show the result like first example. Any ideas ?

Comment: Will the trips always be sequential like you have? Or will it be like trip1, trip2, trip, trip3, trip1 .etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model function that assigns the associative array key as the `name` of the row. Each subsequent item looped will be added to the proper sub array:

```
$query = $this->db->query('...'); // your query
$rows = $query->result_array();
$data = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // assign assoc array index as name
    // all items with the same name will be in the same assoc array
    $data[$row['name']][] = $row;
}
return $data;
```

To display like you have it simply call the model function and do the following:

Controller:

```
$this->load->model('your_model');
$data['items'] = $this->your_model->the_func();
$this->load->view('some_view', $data);
```

In view:

```
foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
    echo $k . '<br>';
    foreach ($v as $i) {
        echo $i['link'];
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```